# Trying to create a random image generator using an array

Tags: geocoding

I'm new to xcode and swiftui and I'm trying to create a random image generator using an array I created of some flower images in the contentview. What I'm hoping it will look like is you click a button and a random flower pops up. I don't mind if the images repeat. Thanks in advance! Here's what I have so far:

```
[import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var flowers = ["carnation", "daffodil", "iris", "lily", "orchid", "peony", "poppy", "rose", "sunflower", "tulip"]


    var body: some View {
        Text("sunflower")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


]
```

Comment: Do you …have images in your project?

Comment: yes! I went ahead and put them into assets.xcassets. There's 10 of them. All 10 names can be seen in the var flowers array above (I'm still new to this so sorry if this doesn't answer your question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [randomElement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994747-randomelement) on your `String Array`, but my recommendation is to convert your array to an enumeration.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  private enum Flower: String, CaseIterable {
    case carnation
    case daffodil
    case iris
    case lily
    case orchid
    case peony
    case poppy
    case rose
    case sunflower
    case tulip

    static var random: Flower {
      allCases.randomElement()!
    }
  }

  @State private var flower: Flower = .random

  var body: some View {
    Button(
      action: { self.flower = .random }
    ) {
      Image(flower.rawValue).renderingMode(.original)
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  private static let flowerNames = [
    "carnation",
    "daffodil",
    "iris",
    "lily",
    "orchid",
    "peony",
    "poppy",
    "rose",
    "sunflower",
    "tulip"
  ]

  private static var randomFlowerName: String {
    flowerNames.randomElement()!
  }

  @State private var flowerName = randomFlowerName

  var body: some View {
    Button(
      action: { self.flowerName = Self.randomFlowerName }
    ) {
      Image(flowerName).renderingMode(.original)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic because it worked!! However, I would really like for it to come specifically from my array. Could you show the code for that?